# I use itext.dll for generating a PDF using ASP.NET and I want a footer in my document?

Tags: itext

I use itext.dll for genrating a PDF using [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) and I want a footer in my document in the form of:

```
    Page 1 of 6 

    HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Page"), new Phrase(" of 6")); 
    footer.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); 
    footer.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); 
    document.setFooter(footer);
```

Is this possible without hardcoding the total number of pages? I.e. is there a method to get the total number pages in a document?

Comment: 14 questions, 1 accepted response...

Comment: This is purely an iTextSharp question, so has little relationship with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that there are (at least) 2 ways of doing this.

One is to create the document without the footer and after that use `PdfStamper` to stamp the page numbers with total on it. But that raised some problems with me when I output the stampers product to `MemoryStream` and there seems to be no way of closing the stamper without closing the stream at the same time.

The other way is to create one instance of `PdfTemplate` that will represent the total page count and add that to every page to footer or where ever you want it.

Next you can use your own `PdfPageEventHelper` class and implement OnCloseDocument method where you can fill the template with total page count:

```
public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    PageCountTemplate.BeginText();
    PageCountTemplate.SetFontAndSize(HeaderFont.BaseFont, HeaderFont.Size);
    PageCountTemplate.ShowText((writer.CurrentPageNumber - 1).ToString());
    PageCountTemplate.EndText();
}
```

I personally also use `OnOpenDocument` to create the template and `OnEndPage` to write it on each page.

EDIT:
To answer Jan's question, `OnCloseDocument` is called only once when the whole doc has been written. When `Doc.Close()` is called I mean.

Comment: will OnCloseDocument called for each page or just the doc?